# How to distribute missions to remote machines?

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing, agent, grid-computing

I am building a system where a server will distribute missions to remote machines and get results.

Is there a free application to create such a system? I would need agents code, service side etc. Preferably agents can be installed on mobiles also.

Comment: What do you mean by "missions"? For distributed computing you could check out BOINC ( http://boinc.berkeley.edu/ ). The client can't be installed on mobiles though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [software agent systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_system) have been worked on for many years in the research community, what you are describing sounds more like [SmartFrog](http://www.smartfrog.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can start programs remotely using ssh.
For certain problems this is the straightforward solution and
I wouldn't try to setup more complicated ones.